# Functions to extend each other in PHP to be more efficient?

Tags: php

I have the following functions in my user class to get the Users ID, Name and Email:

```
public function getUserID(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT userID FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[users] WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
    $userID=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $userID['userID'];
}

public function getUserName(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT userName FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[users] WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
    $userName=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $userName['userName'];
}

public function getUserEmail(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT userEmail FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[users] WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
    $userEmail=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $userEmail['userEmail'];
}
```

But I just feel there would be a better way to do this as it seems wasteful on resources to do 3 almost identical queries.

Is there a way I could do the query once to select all 3 fields and have a function to just get the relevant data?

Comment: Typically when you have an object model from a database, you load it once with a single query and keep the fields in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
class User {
    private $user;
    public function __construct($id, $conn) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[users] WHERE userID=:uid");
            $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$id));
            $this->user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    public function getUserId() {
           return $this->user["userID"];
    }
    // more methods as well or a generic __call e.g.

    public function __call($name, $args) {
         if (substr($name, 0, 3) === "get") { // e.g. getUserName will get userName
             return $this->user[lcfirst(substr($name,3))];
         }
    }

}
```

Then you can just do:

```
 $user = new User($_SESSION["userSession"], $this->conn);
```

You then even persist the model in the session if you want:

```
 $_SESSION["usermodel"] = $user;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to think more before writing code...

```
public function getUser(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[users] WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // get attributes : $user['userName'] ....
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: To make this better, I would store the user in a class property the first time it's loaded. Then on any calls to `getUserEmail()` and similar, check if the user already is loaded, if not, load it and return the email. If not, you will still load the user on each call to `getUser()`.

Comment: But how would I then access just the username for example? `<?php $user->getUser()->$UserNameAttribute; ?>` ??